# Ubuntu 23.1 - Gnome 45.2 - GNOME TWEAKS 42.beta (Release GNOME TWEAKS 45 available ?)

Tags: gnome-tweaks

Is there is recent release for GNOME TWEAKS that is compatible-support Ubuntu 23.1 running Gnome 45 ?  Installed GNOME TWEAKS 42.beta.  Went ok...  BUT cannot use new downloaded 'Themes' etc .  Message :  Shell user-themes extension not enable in TWEAKS-APPEARANCE menu with exclamation mars and EMPTY field..

Someone can help ?

Thanks in advance for for help.

Comment: HI !  Thanks for your rapid answer.  I am a beginner....Ubuntu...so .  Any idea when this package will be avaailable ?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu's 2023-October release is 23.10 (2023 shortened to 23 and October is 10 or *ten*)

Answer (score 0):

Beta versions of software including Gnome Tweaks are intended for developers and beta testers and not intended to installed on live systems. You can try to riun it on bare metal but there are inherent risks in doing so.

The conventual wisdom is if you are not a developer or beta tester and you can't afford to brick your system is to be patient, wait and as soon as the substantive version lands, you should be able to get it by updating the system in GNOME Software

> WARNING! This is beta quality software. This release is intended for GNOME developers and beta testers. For more information about GNOME 46, including the full schedule [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/FortySix)

[This reference](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gnome-46-beta-released/19505/1) explains more.